# Laravel 10 API with jwt, work in localhost but error in hosting

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-10

I create an API project using laravel 10, include JWT, on localhost I can run but on hosting there is an error:

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\TestController] does not exist.

Here's the code I made

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
 {
      function index()
        {
           $test = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'];
           return response()->json([
                'test' => $test,
            ]);
        }
  }
```

**Route api.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\TestController;
//
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
Route::get('/test', [TestController::class, 'index']); 
});
```

In localhost it works:

```
// 20230724104212
// http://localhost:8000/api/v1/test

{
 "test": [
 "Test 1",
 "Test 2",
 "Test 3"
 ]
}
```

But in hosting error:

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\TestController] does not exist.

Comment: Linux file system (host) is case-sensitive. So check your file names and codes

Comment: How did you deploy the code to the linux server? Copy paste? git pull ? If copy paste, you might have pasted the controller in the wrong path. Or possibly the `TestController`'s filename was written as `testcontroller`.....

Comment: Problem Solved. It looks like some vendor files haven't uploaded, perfectly, because I created a new project and it's working. Thank you for giving your participation

Answer (score 1):

run

`composer dump-autoload`

after that, run:

`php artisan optimize:clear`

reference:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload

Comment: I tried that, but a new error appears like this, include(/home/u89324556/application/apibengkelonline/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory